# USB wifi adapter has stopped working, is it the device's or Ubuntu's fault?

Tags: wireless, hardware

I was happily using a TP-LINK TL-WN722N USB wifi adapter on Kubuntu 14.04. Now it has suddenly stopped working. When I plug it, /var/log/syslog says things like these:

```
Sep 30 20:34:08 meles kernel: [47010.291060] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
Sep 30 20:34:08 meles kernel: [47010.319034] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
Sep 30 20:34:08 meles kernel: [47010.319049] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
Sep 30 20:34:08 meles kernel: [47010.319055] usb 3-2: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
Sep 30 20:34:08 meles kernel: [47010.319059] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
Sep 30 20:34:08 meles kernel: [47010.319063] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 12345
Sep 30 20:34:08 meles kernel: [47010.320884] usb 3-2: ath9k_htc: Firmware htc_9271.fw requested
Sep 30 20:34:08 meles ModemManager[802]: <warn>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/usb3/3-2': not supported by any plugin
Sep 30 20:34:08 meles kernel: [47010.784766] usb 3-2: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 51272
Sep 30 20:34:08 meles kernel: [47011.020822] ath9k_htc 3-2:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.250691] ath9k_htc 3-2:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.3
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.250701] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x809c
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.250704] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.250708] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.250711] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x52
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.250715] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CN
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.250717] ath: Regpair used: 0x52
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.254919] ieee80211 phy15: Atheros AR9271 Rev:1
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <info> (wlan1): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <info> (wlan1): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <info> (wlan1): new 802.11 WiFi device (driver: 'ath9k_htc' ifindex: 18)
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <info> (wlan1): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/16
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <info> (wlan1): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <info> (wlan1): bringing up device.
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.344907] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 13
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.843938] ath: phy15: Chip reset failed
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.843951] ath: phy15: Unable to reset channel (2412 Mhz) reset status -22
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.843980] ath: phy15: Unable to set channel
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.945316] ath: phy15: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0xeaffffff
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.946506] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47011.955443] ath: phy15: Failed to wakeup in 500us
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47012.056695] ath: phy15: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0xe41da337
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47012.066754] ath: phy15: Failed to wakeup in 500us
Sep 30 20:34:09 meles kernel: [47012.168010] ath: phy15: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0xe41da337
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles kernel: [47012.192423] ath: phy15: Failed to wakeup in 500us
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles kernel: [47012.293854] ath: phy15: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0xb872752f
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles kernel: [47012.699081] ath: phy15: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0xb872752f
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <warn> (18) failed to find interface name for index
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: (nm-system.c:766):nm_system_iface_get_flags: runtime check failed: (iface != NULL)
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <error> [1443638050.555454] [nm-system.c:768] nm_system_iface_get_flags(): (unknown): failed to get interface link object
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <warn> (18) failed to find interface name for index
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: (nm-system.c:766):nm_system_iface_get_flags: runtime check failed: (iface != NULL)
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <error> [1443638050.555961] [nm-system.c:768] nm_system_iface_get_flags(): (unknown): failed to get interface link object
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <warn> (18) failed to find interface name for index
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: (nm-system.c:766):nm_system_iface_get_flags: runtime check failed: (iface != NULL)
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <error> [1443638050.556434] [nm-system.c:768] nm_system_iface_get_flags(): (unknown): failed to get interface link object
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <warn> (18) failed to find interface name for index
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: (nm-system.c:766):nm_system_iface_get_flags: runtime check failed: (iface != NULL)
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <error> [1443638050.557402] [nm-system.c:768] nm_system_iface_get_flags(): (unknown): failed to get interface link object
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <warn> (18) failed to find interface name for index
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: (nm-system.c:766):nm_system_iface_get_flags: runtime check failed: (iface != NULL)
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <error> [1443638050.557948] [nm-system.c:768] nm_system_iface_get_flags(): (unknown): failed to get interface link object
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles ModemManager[802]: <info>  (net/wlan1): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/usb3/3-2
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <warn> (18) failed to find interface name for index
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: (nm-system.c:766):nm_system_iface_get_flags: runtime check failed: (iface != NULL)
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <error> [1443638050.558456] [nm-system.c:768] nm_system_iface_get_flags(): (unknown): failed to get interface link object
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <warn> (18) failed to find interface name for index
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: (nm-system.c:766):nm_system_iface_get_flags: runtime check failed: (iface != NULL)
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <error> [1443638050.559112] [nm-system.c:768] nm_system_iface_get_flags(): (unknown): failed to get interface link object
Sep 30 20:34:10 meles NetworkManager[1076]: <warn> (18) failed to find interface name for index
```

etc.

It was working fine, then I updated the kernel (and some other things, I guess), unplugged it, rebooted, and it didn't work any more. I tried booting up with the previous kernel, no joy. I've tried in another computer, where it also used to work (but it's been longer since I last tried there), and it's the same.

Nothing lights up in the device, and I'm suspecting there could be something wrong with it and not with the OS. Is there anything else I can do to find out what the problem is?

Comment: It sounds like you've already finished debugging. If it has stopped working on multiple computers and none of the lights come on, the adapter is dead. Moreover the line `usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 13` suggests the adapter is disconnecting when the OS tries to activate the radio. Probably time to buy a new one.

Comment: @TheSchwa I'll try in some other computers (possibly something with Windows too). Actually, I hope the adapter is dead, much easier to fix than if it's a computer problem, and it's less than 2 months old, so I should get a replacement...

Comment: For the record, I got a replacement, and this one works as the other did before, so I'll call it a hardware fault. In the logs, the first line that's different is indeed ``usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 13``, which I don't get with the working device, instead I have ``cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: CN`` and then some more from ``cfg80211``.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, please accept it when you get the chance. Hope your new adapter lasts longer than the last one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you've tried it on multiple computers and the lights on the adapter do not turn on when plugged in, it is almost definitely a hardware problem.

Furthermore, the line `usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 13` suggests the adapter is disconnecting or failing when the OS tries to turn on the radio. Since that message is from the USB driver, it's almost definitely a hardware problem on the adapter.

If you want to debug further you could try installing it on a Windows computer, but it sounds like the adapter is dead. Probably time to get a new one.